# Firebase order by date Desc using Ionic Infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I would like to order a list of comments by date desc (using an ionic infinite scroll) but it doesn't work, the sorting is not okay :

**What I tried :**

```
  // How I push a new comment
  const ref=firebase.database().ref('/comment/'+imageId+'/').push();
  ref.set({
    created_at: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
    ...
  })
```

[image]

**To retrieve and sort by date Desc :**

***ngOnInit() :***

```
  limit: number = 10;
  var items = [];
  this.listComments = db.ref('comment/'+this.imageId).orderByChild("created_at");

  this.listComments.limitToLast(this.limit).on('value', itemList => {
     itemList.forEach(function(data) {
        const user_id=data.val().user_id;
        db.ref('users/' + user_id).on('value',function(snap) {
             items.push({'displayName':snap.val().displayName,'created_at':data.val().created_at});
             return false;
         });
     });
  })
  this.commentArray=items;
 }
```

***onInfiniteScroll(event) :***

```
let items = [];

this.limit += 2;
//same as before
this.listComments.limitToLast(this.limit).on('value', itemList => {
     itemList.forEach(function(data) {
        const user_id=data.val().user_id;
        db.ref('users/' + user_id).on('value',function(snap) {
             items.push({'displayName':snap.val().displayName,'created_at':data.val().created_at});
             return false;
         });
     });
  })

  setTimeout(() => {
     this.commentArray=items;
     event.complete();
   }, 500);
```

**Result:**

[image]

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

`orderByChild` sorts in ascending order ([docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#data-order)). You can create a separate key for descending order that is `created_at * -1`. That would mean older timestamps are greater than newer ones. So maybe something like:

```
const ref = firebase.database().ref('comment').child(imageId).push();
ref.set({
  created_at: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
})
.then(() => {
  return ref.child('created_at').once('value')
  .then((ss) => {
    return ref.child('created_at_desc').set(ss.val() * -1)
  })
})
```